# Windows 8 metro - how to make password text box?

Tags: windows, textbox, passwords

Like whatever I may put inside it will only show *****.
Tried textBox.PasswordChar but didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you should use a [PasswordBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700391.aspx